# Leak of memory in C

Tags: c

In this function, I have leak of memory

```
static int      read_buffer(int const fd, char **buffer)
{
        char    buff[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
        int     ret;

        ret = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
        if (ret > 0)
        {
                buff[ret] = 0;
                if (!(*buffer = ft_strjoin(*buffer, buff)))
                        return (-1);
        }
        return (ret);
}
```

I tried to do this and more solution again.. But I get also leak of memory

```
static int      read_buffer(int const fd, char **buffer)
{
        char    buff[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
        char    *tmp;
        int     ret;

        ret = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
        tmp = *buffer;
        if (ret > 0)
        {
                buff[ret] = 0;
                if (!(*buffer = ft_strjoin(*buffer, buff)))
                        return (-1);
                free(tmp);
        }
        return (ret);
}
```

Here is ft_strjoin function: (can't modify)

```
char    *ft_strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    size_t  size_s1;
    size_t  size_s2;
    char    *strjoin;

    size_s1 = ft_strlen(s1);
    size_s2 = ft_strlen(s2);
    if (!(strjoin = malloc(size_s1 + size_s2 + 1)))
        return (NULL);
    ft_strcpy(strjoin, s1);
    ft_strcat(strjoin, s2);
    return (strjoin);
}
```

How I can resolve this ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Could you explain what makes you think there is a memory leak ? The tool used might also give you some hints on the problem.

Comment: @kebs I used valgrind but it returned me this came about ft_strjoin function

Comment: I enjoy the indentation but use some braces

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, *buffer is already point to something

Comment: The ft_strjoin function allocates memory, but must not free it because it simply returns the new buffer. So we cannot consider ft_strjoin in isolation, however it is the place where memory is allocated so some tools will tell you this. Your read_buffer gets a new, bigger, buffer from ft_strjoin and correctly discards the old smaller one. This still leaves the caller of read_buffer the responsibility of discarding the new buffer whenever you are finished with it. So you need to look at whatever is calling read_buffer.

Comment: strjoin returned by ft_strjoin is leaking

Comment: As @djna has pointed out, your second `read_buffer` will make sure you're not leaking memory to your buffer by reassigning the pointer (you save and free a copy in `tmp`) but you now need to follow where ever you hand that buffer off next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime a function returns malloc'd memory, you've got a hot potato.  You have to free that memory and cannot pass it on unless you've documented you're doing so.  And you mustn't lose hold of (e.g. reuse) the pointer before freeing it.  Below is how I interpret how `read_buffer()` needs to work.  Since "buffer length is unknown" I'm assuming it comes from `malloc` and we can use `realloc`:

```
static int read_buffer(int const fd, char **buffer)
{
    char local_buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1];

    int bytes_read = read(fd, local_buffer, BUFF_SIZE);

    if (bytes_read > 0)
    {
        local_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

        char *joined = ft_strjoin(*buffer, local_buffer);

        if (joined != NULL)
        {
            *buffer = realloc(*buffer, strlen(joined) + 1);

            if (*buffer != NULL)
            {
                ft_strcpy(*buffer, joined);
            }
            else
            {
                bytes_read = -1;
            }

            free(joined);
        }
        else {
            bytes_read = -1;
        }
    }

    return bytes_read;
}
```

Note that there are a lot of potential pitfalls that you need to test for and recover from.

If you're reading from the user directly, and don't want newlines as part of the concatenation of strings, you can replace this line:

```
     local_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
```

with something like:

```
    if (local_buffer[bytes_read - 1] == '\n')
    {
        local_buffer[bytes_read - 1] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        local_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
    }
```

Assuming the above newline fix, here's a small test program I wrote:

```
int main() {

    char *buffer = malloc(1);

    *buffer = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        (void) read_buffer(0, &buffer);

        puts(buffer);
    }

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

**RESULT**

```
> ./a.out
abcdefg
abcdefg
hijklmn
abcdefghijklmn
opqrstu
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot of for your explanation !
But **buffer length is unknown

Comment: Thanks, @t4Planeur, that explains the double char** pointer -- we need to use `realloc()` and replace the memory allocated if it's insufficient.  I've revised my example accordingly.